# Ubuntu terminal wildcard and tab key to develop full results

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

In a previous work I have not been curious in the terminal settings (for Linux2_6-64) but I could use a really good feature: using the star '*' character at the command line end and pressing TAB, the command line will be expanded with all matching results. As a simple example, having this repository:

```
vpnLogs$ ls -la
total 1240
drwxrwxr-x 2  .
drwxrwxr-x 3  ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1  logs_vpn_IPv4_ok_verbose.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1  logs_vpn_IPv6_bis_verbose.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1  logs_vpn_IPv6_fails_verbose.txt
```

I can type

```
vpnLogs$ rm -f logs_vpn_IPv*
```

and press TAB, then the command line will be completed will all matches (wanted):

```
vpnLogs$ rm -f logs_vpn_IPv4_ok_verbose.txt logs_vpn_IPv6_bis_verbose.txt logs_vpn_IPv6_fails_verbose.txt
```

instead, the current result is only the first match (unwanted):

```
vpnLogs$ rm -f logs_vpn_IPv4_ok_verbose.txt
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, there is something I should probably set in my .bashrc but I do not find what.

Does someone knows this ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. There are some other SE sites where it may be appropriate, including an Ubuntu-specific one and a Unix & Linux one.

Comment: hm indeed:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1840843

Solution is to used Alt+Shift+8 instead of Shift+8 for the wildcard (on English keyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using bash, depending on the system you can use one of these two key combinations:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd>

This expands the wildcard `*` with all the possible matches. If a directory `dir` contains the files `aa`, `ab` and `ba`, the command `ls dir/a*` is expanded to `ls dir/aa dir/ab`.

Comment: indeed it was what I wanted (Alt+Shift+8 for Alt+*)